# keeps throwing error, ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: oracle

```
Select tran_date,tran_particular, (select tran_amt from tbaadm.dtd where part_tran_type = 'D') DR,
(select tran_amt from tbaadm.dtd where part_tran_type = 'C')CR 
from tbaadm.dtd ,tbaadm.gam;
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: a subquery that is expected to return one row is returning more that one. You have to subqueries, check them. Also, no join conditions? And even, you should consider switching to ANSI join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One (or both) subqueries returned more than a single row.

There's nothing much WE can do about it as only you know what to do in such cases.

One option (which isn't smart at all) is to fetch `min` or `max` value, e.g.

```
Select tran_date,
       tran_particular, 
       (select min(tran_amt) from tbaadm.dtd where part_tran_type = 'D') DR,  --> here
       (select min(tran_amt) from tbaadm.dtd where part_tran_type = 'C') CR   --> here
from tbaadm.dtd, tbaadm.gam;
```

Smarter option is to make sure you return only one row; maybe by including additional condition(s) into these `where` clauses?

Or, skip subqueries entirely and use join (which you do - cross join; probably not what you intended to do). `CASE` might solve your `dr` and `cr` columns; if not, consider self-join.

Comment: Select tran_date,tran_particular,
(case when part_tran_type = 'D' then tran_amt else null end) as DR,
(case when part_tran_type = 'C' then tran_amt else null end) as CR
from tbaadm.dtd ,tbaadm.gam where gam.acid = dtd.acid;

Comment: How do I format my tran_amt as money in this sql statement using this format ----PRINT FORMATMESSAGE('The number is: %s', format(5000000.759145678, '#,##0.00'))------?


Select acct_name,tran_date,tran_particular,
(case when part_tran_type = 'D' then tran_amt else 0 end) as DR,
(case when part_tran_type = 'C' then tran_amt else 0 end) as CR
from tbaadm.dtd ,tbaadm.gam where gam.acid = dtd.acid;